# What is the best way to debug a crashing explorer.exe?

Tags: debugging, crash, explorer, windows-explorer

I work for an orginization that has a custom built Access/SQL Application running in house. We have a problem Explorer.exe throwing an error and crashing.

This is a picture of the crash:
[image]

What is the best way to start tracking this problem down and finding a solution ?

Comment: Wait... How does your program have anything to do with Explorer? Are you writing an add-in for it? Manipulating it at run time? Hosting viruses or virus scanners? I'm confused...

Comment: We are not sure how or why the program is crashing explore.exe We check for API calls but we only due one or two during the initial start up of the application. 

We are definitely not hosting viruses or scanners :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure WinDBG is installed, set it up as the default debugger then use Analyze and get a crash dump.

The next time you get that dialog click "OK" to attach in WinDbg

Comment: .symfix ; .reload ; kn100  # (Comment box eats newlines)

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that if you attach a debugger to explorer, then break, that you should not try to do anything in the debugger that invokes a call to explorer or you will deadlock the debugger. This can be surprisingly tricky as it means you cannot open a "File Open" dialog, print, browse to another computer and any number of other things.